# Ctl+F not opening the find dialog

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys

This is a bit of an irritating problem that I've been having with Ubuntu 11.04. Hitting Ctl+F is supposed to open up the find dialog in the currently open program, but instead it is opening up what looks like an xterm window (See screenshot below).[image: Screenshot of window that opens]

I took a look in the keyboard shortcuts window, but I can't seem to find the solution in there. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer. As it turns out when you install xbindkeys it installs a default config file that remaps the ctrl+f shortcut to open xterm.